# Can't change the size of QFrame

Tags: c++, forms, authentication, qt5

**mainwindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QFrame>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QFrame* loginForm = new QFrame(this);
    QFormLayout* loginFormLayout = new QFormLayout(loginForm);
    QLabel* LogInLabel = new QLabel("<h1> Login </h1>", this);
    QLabel* UsernameLabel = new QLabel("Username: ", this);
    QLabel* PasswordLabel = new QLabel("Password: ", this);
    QLineEdit* usernameLineEdit = new QLineEdit();
    QLineEdit* passwordLineEdit = new QLineEdit();

    usernameLineEdit -> setFrame(false);
    usernameLineEdit -> setMaxLength(30);
    passwordLineEdit -> setFrame(false);
    passwordLineEdit -> setMaxLength(30);
    LogInLabel -> setStyleSheet("QLabel { font-family: Arial font-weight: bold }");
    loginFormLayout -> setHorizontalSpacing(0);
    loginFormLayout -> setVerticalSpacing(0);
    loginFormLayout -> addRow(UsernameLabel, usernameLineEdit);
    loginFormLayout -> addRow(PasswordLabel, passwordLineEdit);
    loginFormLayout -> setFieldGrowthPolicy(QFormLayout::FieldsStayAtSizeHint);
    loginFormLayout -> setFormAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop);
    loginForm -> setLayout(loginFormLayout);
    loginForm -> setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Plain);
    loginForm -> setFrameRect(QRect(440, 134, 400, 300));
    loginForm -> setLineWidth(20);
    this -> setCentralWidget(loginForm);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I did not change anything in `mainwindow.h`. I want a *QFrame* with *QFormLayout* inside consisting of two rows of *QLabel-QLineEdit* pairs. I want the whole thing to be 400px wide and 300px high with the top left corner of the *QFrame* at (440, 134). Could you help me find out why I do not achieve the described result?

Comment: Could someone please answer? I'm kind of really frustrated by now.

Comment: Where do you specify the width and height to be equal to 400, resp. 300px?

Comment: Oh I am sorry! In the line loginForm -> setFrameRect(QRect(0, 0, 15, 20)); it should've say loginForm -> setFrameRect(QRect(440, 134, 400, 300));

Comment: Try the following: 1. Instead of _setFrameRect_ use _setGeometry_. 2. Comment out `this -> setCentralWidget(loginForm);`

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you so much!!! I think that setCentralWidget function changes the size of passed widget to fit whole window. Thank you!!!

Comment: Would you like to add it as an answer so I can mark it as best one?

Comment: I am glad that it worked! As an additional piece of advice, you don't need to create the QLabels _UsernameLabel_ and _PasswordLabel_ by yourself. Just call `addRow` with the text you want to be displayed as a first argument, i.e. `loginFormLayout -> addRow("Username: ", usernameLineEdit);` and `loginFormLayout -> addRow("Password: ", passwordLineEdit);`. This will shorten your code a little bit.

Comment: You are right! I haven't thought about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget` causes the widget passed as an argument to become a subject of the *QMainWindow*'s layout, thus its size is managed by the layout from this time on. To achieve the desired result do the following:

1. Instead of `QFrame::setFrameRect` use `QFrame::setGeometry`
2. Comment out `this -> setCentralWidget(loginForm)`